# spring boot microservices return 301 on POST calls

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have multiples services running on AWS.  I have a spring boot gateway that directs to services based upon url defined in application.properties.  However, on POST calls a 301 is returned, and this redirect breaks the flow.  I don't see anything in the gateway or subsequent service log files as to why this is happening, so I don't know how to troubleshoot it.  A basic flow is:

***user --https (via port 443)--> spring-gateway:8081 --http--> service***

I don't have anything special in the gateway service for looking up - all services are registered with the Eureka service.  Here is the application.properties info:

```
server.port=8081
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework  
feign.hystrix.enabled=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
spring.cloud.config.name=config-service
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = false
spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.'[/**]'=
allowedOrigins="localhost:8080"
allowedMethods="GET POST DELETE PUT"
allowedHeaders="Content-Type"
```

and here is one of the services that is being attempted to POST (GET works):

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].id=orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri=lb://orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[0]=Path=/payment/**,/order/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[1]=Method=GET, POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[2]=Header=APIKEY, (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[0]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
```

Here is the response returned from somewhere on each POST:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

And the response header has:

```
Server | awselb/2.0
Date   | Mon, 23 Jan 2023 01:39:05 GMT
Content-Type | text/html
Content-Length | 134
Connection  | keep-alive
Location | https://my-url:8081/orders-service/payment
```

If I take that Location url and put it back in Postman then it completes correctly.

I tried adding a url rewrite in the hopes that gateway would send the request to the correct location with:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[1]=RewritePath=/(?<segment>.*),/payment/$\{segment},/order/$\{segment}
```

But apparently it doesn't work that way as I get the same issue.

If someone can explain why all calls get an auto return from my Spring gateway of 301 that might point me in the right direction.  Ideally the request just processes without getting the 301 in the middle of the flow.  I thought one of the gateway filters would do this, but I can't find an example of this.

**EDIT **
I noticed when testing with Postman that if the option to "follow redirects" is enabled then everything flows right.  This obviously won't work on my mobile app but perhaps that is a clue what is happening?  I have gone thru the code and nowhere is a 301 explicitly returned by gateway or any service.

Comment: Of course, it's about impossible for us tell why you're getting a 301.
I suggest looking a the actual header that's returned (in Postman), and see where it's redirecting to. That should give you a clue as to what's going on.

One possibility is if the api that you are calling uses HTTPS and you are trying to access it with a "http://....." url. When things are configured properly, that would redirect to the "https://...." url.

Comment: Would this impact both POST and GET?  I see the full url Location in the response headers and it has https, but I am not sure if the service needs to be setup to receive https calls.
Is it possible to use a RedirectToGatewayFilterFactory or something to have the server follow the redirect?

Comment: can you try to remove lb pattern and test.
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri=orders-service

Comment: I removed it but still get the same 301 with the full url in the Location response header.  Entry now looks like:

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].id=orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri=orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[0]=Path=/payment/**,/order/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[1]=Method=GET, POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[2]=Header=APIKEY, (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[0]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter

Comment: You can further debug by enabling wiretap logs in the [spring cloud gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#wiretap):

logging.level.reactor.netty=DEBUG
spring.cloud.gateway.httpserver.wiretap=true
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.wiretap=true

Comment: did you try to disabling the HTTPS protocol in the gateway configuration to see if it resolves the 301 redirect issue?