# spring gateway always returns 301, how to continue processing

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

This is clarification of the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201771/spring-boot-microservices-return-301-on-post-calls)

I have a spring gateway that uses eureka server to route requests to registered spring boot eureka clients.

What I am seeing is that every request results in a 301 redirect containing a Location header.  It seems that because the request is received on https://my-api.io/payment/payment-intent spring-gateway looks it up based upon these rules:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
feign.hystrix.enabled=false
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = true
 ....
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].id=orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].uri=lb://orders-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[0]=Path=/payment/**,/order/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[1]=Method=GET, POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].predicates[2]=Header=APIKEY, (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[0]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
## these next two apparently have no impact
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[1]=RewritePath=/(?<segment>.*),/payment/$\{segment},/order/$\{segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[11].filters[2]=RedirectTo=301, lb://orders-service
```

And then returns the Response Headers:

```
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2023 17:58:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://my-api.io:8081/payment/payment-intent
```

If I enable "follow redirects" in Postman or curl, then it works fine.  But that won't work in a mobile app, so I really need to have spring-gateway just route the call on first pass.  I don't know if this is because the routes.uri defines the as coming from the load-balancer (since ports are dynamic and there are likely multiple instances) url so it seems like a different url or what.

I am desperately trying to find a way so that the request is just processed and not bounced back with a 301.

Comment: Gateway doesn't support following redirects. It simply passed the response back to the client

Comment: do you mean the calling client will always get the 301 and have to act upon it by using the Location Header value and resubmitting the request?

Comment: Yes, gateway just passes responses back.

Comment: last question so I understand.  Gateway gets the request, sees the call is for another service so it returns the url of the server to request to.  Is this by design or the way I have gateway incorrectly setup?  I ask because it seems like I am duplicating all calls, which would indicate scalability & cost issues.

Comment: Gateway doesn't see anything. It just passes data thru

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have context around the issue it turns out the issue was not with Spring Gateway since its just a passthru (after some validation).  Thanks to [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) I was able to rule out gateway and realize it was a forwarding issue in AWS.